# Java get value of name attribute

Tags: java, spring

I have input fields that get generated dynamically.

eg.

```
<input name="needThisValueInJava"  value="DontNeedThis">
```

using `request.getParameter()` 
I need to know the name property
I will not know the name as there will sometimes be more than 1  and
I can't increment the field(text1,text2....textN)

the names will populate usually like using **JavaScript**

```
 <input name="fname"  value="DontNeedThis">
 <input name="address"  value="DontNeedThis">
 <input name="lname"  value="DontNeedThis">
 <input name="dob"  value="DontNeedThis">
```

So in **JAVA** I need the 4 name values then I will loop them and get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
Enumeration en=request.getParameterNames();
 while(en.hasMoreElements())
 {
  Object objOri=en.nextElement();
  String param=(String)objOri;
  String value=req.getParameter(param);
  pw.println("Parameter Name is '"+param+"' and Parameter Value is'"+value+"'");
 }
```

Hope it helps.